# Spring Cloud Dependencies Issue

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-cloud

I am getting this error message spammed when running my build in our CI servers:

```
[Fatal Error] spring-cloud-dependencies-Hoxton.RC2.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] spring-cloud-dependencies-Hoxton.RC2.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] spring-cloud-dependencies-parent-2.2.0.RC2.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
```

Has anyone had this problem before? Doesn't happen locally.

Comment: Does your company have a maven proxy? Hoxton.RC2 isn't on maven central since it is a release candidate. Try with Hoxton.SR11. Also Hoxton is no longer supported

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, the issue I have now is that some of our CI servers reside in a different network to others, so this sometimes fails sometimes not. I might check gradle what pulls this in exactly as we don't even use it.